# Casting int to double and rounding off to last whole number

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm stuck with a little issue here, say you have the following code:

```
int whole = 0;
double decimal = 88.00

whole = decimal / 1.5; //now the answer is 58.66
```

So here's the issue, explicitly casting a double to an int is easy enough. But if I do this now 'whole' is going to be set to 59. This - is not so good, I want it to be set to the last whole number (being 58).

How do you do this in C#?

Comment: Use Round. I think that would work.

Comment: Use `Math.Floor(decimal/1.5);`

Comment: Anyone also had a WTF moment "double decimal type?" :)

Comment: Yes! Replace "decimal" with "aaa". :p

Comment: @John and suddenly ancient x86 ascii math is involved..

Comment: @DeanGrobler, since when does casting to an int round? It truncated last time I checked.

Comment: Can you repeat with other words, @harold? I didn't understand what you mean...

Comment: @John `aaa` is x86's "ASCII Adjust after Addition" instruction .. just a joke, it's not important.

Comment: ah, ok. I didn't know. Thank you! I used it as variable. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx):

```
whole = (int)Math.Floor(decimal / 1.5);
```

Answer (score 7):

To round doubles to integers, you have 4 basic math functions:

1. [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4h66hd) - Rounds to the nearest whole number (or user specified number of deciml places), and lets you choose to round middle points up or down.
2. [`Math.Floor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor) - Rounds to the first whole number toward negative infinity.
3. [`Math.Ceiling()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling) - Rounds to the first whole number toward positive infinity.
4. [`Math.Truncate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate) - Rounds to the first whole number toward zero.

I think you want either `Floor` or `Truncate`. Both round down for positive numbers, but `Truncate` rounds -3.6 to -3, while `Floor` rounds it to -4.

Casting to `int` does the same as truncating, so you can use that if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

If you cast `double` to `int`, the answer will NOT be 59 -- it will be 58. When casting `double` to `int`, the value will be rounded **towards zero**. So, this is sufficient:

```
int whole = 0;
double x = 88.00;
whole = (int)(x / 1.5); // whole will be 58
```

Comment: @John The OP states "I want it to be set to the last whole number (being 58)".

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx) if you want to round to the last whole number, and [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w37edx9) if you want to round to the next.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the double value into `int`:

```
whole = (int)(decimal / 1.5);
```

Also, you can use `Math.Floor(doubleValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need rounding, it's pretty common to use:
whole = (int)(decimal / 1.5 + 0.5);
Without the 0.5, you're truncating, not rounding.

If you have a rounding function in your math libraries, that's good too.  Some of these will do the odd/even thing for rounding 0.5 to avoid a little bit of data skew.